# Properties that were not listed in fluid-form overwritten after submit

Tags: forms, typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In my extbase 6.2 extension (built with extension builder) I have:

- An `appointment` that has

  - a `lawyer` that has

    - specializations (called `expertises` in this example).

In my form I simply want to edit the `expertises`, but every time I hit submit  my `lawyer`'s properties are emptied except for the `expertises` - those work, even their values are correct.
When I debug the object in fluid the lawyer is there and everything is correct.
This is the only place in my fluid form where I wrote the word "lawyer".

```
<f:for each="{appointment.lawyer.expertises}" as="expertise" iteration="i">  
   <f:form.checkbox property="lawyer.expertises.{i.index}.checked" value="1"/>
   <f:for each="{expertise.subExpertises}" as="subExpertise" iteration="j">
      <f:form.checkbox property="lawyer.expertises.{i.index}.subExpertises.{j.index}.checked" value="1"/>
   </f:for>
</f:for>
```

Usually my properties of `appointment` don't get overwritten just because I don't write a form input-field for them.
**So why are the properties of `appointment.lawyer` overwritten and how can I keep this from happening?**

Unfortunately I have no idea what TYPO3 is doing in order to build an object from my form so any hints on that would be appreciated too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not that easy to edit the properties of related elements.

What TYPO3 does in your case is that the original related `lawyer` record (and also the original `expertises`) is detached from the `appointment` object and a new one is created instead, that is why you think the other properties are emptied. You will also see that, if you look up your elements in the list view, there will be more and more each time you save it. The reason is that the form is not automatically generated with the `lawyer`'s and `expertises`'s uids so TYPO3 thinks that these are new objects.

There is one solution I know (if someone knows a better one, please share) **But you need to read the whole description**:
You have to manually add the uid field in your form for every related object. Assuming that your form has `name="appointment"`

```
<f:form.hidden name="appointment[lawyer][__identity]" value="{appointment.lawyer.uid}" />

<f:form.hidden name="appointment[lawyer][expertises][{i.index}][__identity]" value="{expertise.uid}"/>
```

You will also have to do it for the subproperties.

**Important!**
That way the user can also manipulate the ids and modify the objects that he is not supposed to have access to, so you have to check the relations before saving. For that you can use the `_getCleanProperty('xx')` method of a domain object to get the original data of it.

```
if ($appointment->getLawyer()->getUid() != $appointment->_getCleanProperty('lawyer')->getUid()) {
    die('error');
}
```

You need to check all the relations that can be manipulated that way of course.

Comment: awesome, it seems to work - but how do I check for nested properties?
 `foreach ($appointment->getLawyer()->getExpertises() as $expertise) {
            if ($expertise->getUid() != $appointment->_getCleanProperty('lawyer.expertises')->getUid()) {
                die('error');
            }` gives me the error: `Call to a member function getUid() on a non-object`

Comment: You probably have a parent field in the `expertise` model. Then you can check if the parent has changed: `if ($expertise->_getCleanProperty('parentField')->getUid() != $lawyer->getUid()) { die('error'); }` 

PS: you should always compare the ids and not the whole object, because then all properties and nested objects are recursively compared and it is damn slow.

Comment: no, unfortunately I don't have a parent property in my model because it would be a drag to set the parent in the child object AND the child in the parent object every time I add a record manually in the backend (I actually haven't tried it out - could it set the other property automatically for me? I doubt it - I built it with extension builder). To keep a tree structure I only have children properties in my parent models. If you know a good way of dealing with this I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: if you have a 1:n relation then you can use the TCA type `inline`. With that type there must be a parent field and it is automatically filled.